# HtmlUnit Does not get content after click

Tags: java, click, htmlunit

I am tying to parse a website with html unit. The process basically;

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5 * 1000);
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://www.exapmle.com"); //here it waits to run js code.

HtmlUnorderedList ul = (HtmlUnorderedList) page.getByXPath("//ul[contains(@class, 'class-name')]").get(0);
HtmlListItem li = (HtmlListItem) ul.getChildNodes().get(1); // I want to click li and get result page. But it takes a little time to execute.

li.click();

client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5 * 1000); //At here it does not do what I want.
```

After that when I check the page, I see that its content does not change.

What can I do to get correct page result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try polling for a javascript condition to be true

```
int attempts = 20;
int pollMillis = 500;
boolean success = false;
for (int i = 0; i < attempts && !success; i++) {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(pollMillis);
    if (someJavascriptCondition == true) {
        success = true;
    }
}
if (!success) throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Condition not met after %s millis", attempts * pollMillis);
```

A similar technique discussed [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html)

Comment: I do not have such a java script condition :/

Comment: Of course you do. Check that a spinner image has stopped or a div has updated etc etc

Answer (score 0):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient;
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://www.exapmle.com"); 
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5 * 1000);
Thread.sleep(10*1000);// this code will waite to 10 seconds
HtmlUnorderedList ul = (HtmlUnorderedList) page.getByXPath("//ul[contains(@class, 'class-name')]").get(0);
HtmlListItem li = (HtmlListItem) ul.getChildNodes().get(1); // I want to click li and get result page. But it takes a little time to execute.

li.click();

client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5 * 1000); 
// this code will waite to 10 seconds
Thread.sleep(10*1000);
```

> use Thread.sleep() instead of waitForBackgroundJavaScript
>   works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScriptJobManager to check the amount of JavaScript jobs that have yet to complete. Try the following code after you call `click()`.

```
JavaScriptJobManager manager = page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
while (manager.getJobCount() > 0) {
    System.out.printlin("Jobs remaining: " + manager.getJobCount());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

You may want to add another way to end the while loop in case your JavaScript jobs never finish. Personally, I start terminating jobs manually with:

```
JavaScriptJob job = manager.getEarliestJob();
System.out.println("Stopping job: " + job.getId());
manager.stopJob(job.getId());
```

Hope this helps.